# Is it possible average an information criterion across models?

Tags: goodness-of-fit, aic, garch, model-comparison, in-sample

Is it possible to take the average of information criterion like the AIC?

For my model comparison, I have 24 different models. I use 4 different GARCH models each with 6 different distributions for the innovations. Now I have calculated the information criterion AIC to find the best in-sample fit. Now my question is if I can group the models from a certain GARCH model and take the average AIC of these models. Now I do this as well with the other 3 GARCH models. Next, I have 4 rankings of the average AIC of the different GARCH models. Is this a good way of comparing which models have a better fit?

Comment: the question is why do you want to do such a meaningless thing?

Comment: @utobi To give a ranking for the four different GARCH models? Moreover, I will also do this to provide an order of the six conditional distributions used. Why would it be meaningless?

Comment: you may rank the 24 different models by their respective AICs.

Comment: but the question is what are you looking for? I mean, are looking for best model? or a kind of average between the 24 models?

Comment: @utobi I have, but wouldn't it be a conclusion that a certain model or distribution on average performs better? I was just wondering if this wouldn't cause any implications

Comment: Say you have 24 different ice cream flavors. You group them by 4 and blend together and taste only the four-flavor-mix. Would this really help to make a choice? I'd argue that the mix of four flavors doesn't necessarily need to be tasty even if any of the individual flavors was good.

Comment: @Tim I am mixing two flavours here. If 1 flavour on average has the best two-flavour-mix, doesn't that imply it also has a higher potential to mix with other flavours?

Comment: If anything, you should take a max rather than an average. But an AIC is not an omnibus. There's no free lunch. You can't just present a simulation and say method A is the best because it beats "most" other of your artificial scenarios.